# jQuery DataTables Authentication

Tags: jquery, datatables, basic-authentication

I'm using authentication for my Ajax requests in jQuery. I successfully call my API to retrieve JSON. Previously I was generating HTML with the JSON output but now I want to use DataTables on my data.

I'm chaining two Ajax requests here. The first request gets the store information and from that the retailer ID. This is passed to my API as a parameter which pull the sales for a particular retailer. myStore is the success callback for the first Ajax request.

I've tried a few different iterations with DataTables but still can't get this working.

**How can I populate DataTables with the JSON data while using authentication in my request?**

```
function myStore(result) {
            //console.log(result[0].storeid);
            result = result[0];
            $( "#header" ).append(
                result.storename
            );
            $( "#content" ).append(
                "<p>" + result.street + "<br>"
                + result.city + ", " + result.state + " " + result.zipcode + "<br></p>"
            );

            $('#sales_table').dataTable( {
                "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
                    oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                        "dataType": 'json',
                        "type": "GET",
                        "url": 'api/sales/' + result.retailerid,
                        "beforeSend": function(xhr){
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
                            "Basic " + btoa(storeObject.user + ":" + storeObject.password));
                        },
                    });
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "title" },
                    { "data": "description" }
                ]
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataTables accepts various data types for its [ajax](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#object) option, one of them is an `Object`, see the excerpt from the manual below:

> As an object, the `ajax` object is passed to [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) allowing fine control of the Ajax request. DataTables has a number of default parameters which you can override using this option.

Your code could be changed as follows:

```
function myStore(result) {
   //console.log(result[0].storeid);
   result = result[0];
   $( "#header" ).append(
      result.storename
   );
   $( "#content" ).append(
      "<p>" + result.street + "<br>"
      + result.city + ", " + result.state + " " + result.zipcode + "<br></p>"
   );

   $('#sales_table').dataTable( {
      "ajax": {
         "url": 'api/sales/' + result.retailerid,
         "dataType": 'json',
         "type": "GET",
         "beforeSend": function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
               "Basic " + btoa(storeObject.user + ":" + storeObject.password));
         }
      },
      "columns": [
         { "data": "title" },
         { "data": "description" }
      ]
   });
}
```

Comment: That actually got a response! The problem now is that I think dataTables is expecting my JSON response to be wrapped by "data" (see the Ajax tab on https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) when my JSON is not. It's just a collection of objects with no header. Here's a sample: [{"saleid":"1","description":"My First Sale","retailerid":"1","expires":"Jul 02","title":"First Sale"},{"saleid":"2","description":"My Second Sale","retailerid":"1","expires":"Jul 02","title":"Second Sale"}] I'm getting this error in Firebug: TypeError: aData is undefined for ( i=0 ; i<aData.length ; i++ )

Comment: @KenJ, use `"dataSrc":""` as a property in `"ajax"` to allow array of objects in the result.